# Write pandas dataframe to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I've got some weird problem here and stuck. I'm rewriting python script that generates some CSV files, and I need to write the same info on MySQL server.

I've managed to get it working... somehow.

Here is the part that creates CSV:

```
final_table.get_tunid_town_pivot().to_csv('result_pivot_tunid_town_' + ConsoleLog.get_curr_date_underline() + '.csv', sep=';')
```

And here is the part that loads data into MySQL table:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='test', passwd='test', db='test')
final_table.get_tunid_town_pivot().to_sql(con=conn, name='TunID', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql', index=False, chunksize=10000)
conn.close()
```

The problem is that there are 4 columns in dataframe, but in MySQL i get only one last column. I have no idea why is that happening, and I found zero similar problems. Any help please?

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? Further, can you try this with using an SQLAlchemy engine (see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries). Lastly, can you show `final_table.get_tunid_town_pivot().info()` ?

Comment: SQLAlchemy was my first try with same result. info shows this: MultiIndex: 258 entries, (21, 85.21.230.5, eriwan) to (21, 85.21.230.5, zmm)
Data columns (total 1 columns):
Count    258 non-null int64. How i could be possible that this table have 1 column?

Comment: pandas version is 0.17.1

Comment: So you have 1 column in your dataframe? The it sounds logical to also have 1 column in the SQL table? If you want to include the MultiIndex as columns in the SQL table, specify `index=True` instead of `index=False`

Comment: Yes, i've already tried to use `index=True`, and it gives me error `ValueError: Invalid MySQL identifier 'Tunnel ID'`

Comment: Can you try that with an sqlalchemy engine? (that should work correctly) Or otherwise use `reset_index` before `to_sql` (see my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DataFrame has (probably due to the pivoting) a MultiIndex of 3 levels and only 1 column. By default, `to_sql` will also write the index to the SQL table, but you did specify `index=False`, so only the one column will be written to SQL.

So either do not specify to not include the index (so use `index=True`), or either reset the index and write the frame then (`df.reset_index().to_sql(..., index=False)`).

Also note that using a pymysql connection in `to_sql` is deprecated (it should give you a warning), you have to use it through an SQLAlchemy engine.